# Error saying Parsing Error: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, parsing, unexpected-token

I am getting error in a conditional statement in for loop as unexpected token.

I am clueless to figure what is wrong in the expected character and unexpected character in the line 46 (which is the for loop `for (var d = 1; d<=daysInWeek; d++)`).

````
    let numberOfDays = this.state.dateClicked.daysInMonth()
    var dayArray = []
    const daysInWeek = 7;
    let weeks = parseInt(numberOfDays/7)
    for (var w = 1; w <= weeks; w++) {
      dayArray.push(<div className="row justify-content-center">)
      var dayNumber;
      for (var d = 1; d<=daysInWeek; d++) {
        dayNumber = (w-1)*(daysInWeek) + d
        dayArray.push(<div className="col-md-1" style={style.cell} key={dayNumber} onClick={this.captureDay.bind(this,{dayNumber})}>{dayNumber}</div>)
      }
      dayArray.push(</div>)
    }
    let remdays = this.state.dateClicked.daysInMonth()%7
    if (remdays>= 0) {
      dayArray.push(<div className="row justify-content-center">)
    }
    for (let r = 1; r <= remdays; r++){
      var dayN = 28+r
      <div className="col-md-1" style={style.cell} key={r} onClick={this.captureDay.bind(this,{dayN})}>{dayN}</div>
    }
    dayArray.push(</div>)
    return dayArray;
    }```

I am getting error as " Line 46:  Parsing error: Unexpected token"
(Line 46 is the for loop)
```for (var d = 1; d<=daysInWeek; d++)```
````

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is you are pushing an unclosed div to the array. You cannot create unclosed elements and pass them around in reactjs, check this answer for more details:
[Render unclosed html elements pushed into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592642/render-unclosed-html-elements-pushed-into-an-array)

For your problem, you can do something like this to build your result.

First, generate the inner content and put them to an array.

```
 for (var d = 1; d<=daysInWeek; d++) {
    dayNumber = (w-1)*(daysInWeek) + d
    dayArray.push(<div className="col-md-1" style={style.cell} key={dayNumber} onClick={this.captureDay.bind(this,{dayNumber})}>{dayNumber}</div>)
  }
```

Then wrap them with the parent div,

```
const result = (
  <div className="row justify-content-center">
   {dayArray}
  </div>
)
```